# Regex to look for good phone numbers

Tags: regex

How do I write a regexp that looks for a good phone number in a string?

Match criteria:

> - last 4 characters are the same
> - last 3 characters are the same
> - last and 3rd last are 0

Example on matches:

> - 1-310-123-4444
> - 1-310-123-3444
> - 1-310-123-4040

Comment: do you care what the other numbers are?

Comment: @dramzy No not really this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last 3 or 4 characters are the same

```
(\d)\1{2,3}$
```

last and 3rd last are 0

```
0\d0$
```

**Final Expression**

```
/(?:(\d)\1{2,3}$)|(?:0\d0$)/
```

Demo Page

http://regexr.com/39on2

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how a valid phone number should be formed in general, but if you're just looking to validate the last four digits, this will do what you are looking for: `(\d-(?:\d{3}-){2}(?:(?:(\d)\2{3})|(?:\d(\d)\3{2})|(?:\d0\d0)))`. You can test it with various inputs [here](http://regex101.com/r/uS9xS2/1).

Answer (score 1):

http://regexr.com/39omv

I come up with this one which works fine on all your 3 criteria so far, it seems.

pattern I use: \d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d-((\d)\2{3}|\d(\d)\3{2}|\d0\d0)